# How to set a default module in SugarCRM 7

Tags: sugarcrm

Hy Guys,

In SugarCRM 6 there is an attribute in config.php file named default_module which indicates that after a user gets logged in successfull he will be redirected to that specified module. For example if i have mentioned Contacts as the default module then the user will see the Contacts module as his first module (in other words the landing page become Contacts list view) after getting loged-in instead of the standard Home module.

But this parameter is not working in SugarCRM 7.

Any ideas hows to implement this logic in an upgrade safe way in SugarCRM 7. One of the possibilities that comes to my mind is to make a redirect in after_login logic hook to a specified module.

Can you give me any other options/ideas that can be implemented in this scenario?